# How do I summarize this data to unique rows in a list of duplicates in excel?

Tags: excel, duplicates

I have data like this in my sheet - *(I've highlighted like rows for better understanding)*

[image]

As you might see, 'A' has 3 occurrences with the values 1, 4, & 5; 'B' with 3 & 6; 'C' & 'D' with single values 6 & 2 respectively. I want to summarize this data, so it looks like this (image below), having only unique names with their values added -

[image]

How do I do this? Does anyone have any ideas? Kindly guide... Thanks! :)

Comment: It's possible with formulae yes but have you thought about a pivot table yet?

Comment: Hi, @JvdV! How can a pivot table help in this case? I haven't used pivot tables before so I don't know how should I start

Comment: Start by searching online for "pivot tables excel". Click on the first result you find that will most likely be [this one](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576). Try to create the pivot table yourselves. After a few mistakes you'll figure out that you probably need a pivot table with the Name in the rows' field and Value in the values' field (as sum of values).

Comment: @BigSantuary as already mentioned above clearly by JvdV Sir and Evil Blue Monkey using a `Pivot Table` will be the most easiest way, perhaps if you are using `MS365` note you can use a formula like so, `=LET(u,UNIQUE(A2:A8),
CHOOSE({1,2},u,SUMIF(A2:A8,u,B2:B8)))` assuming the range starts from A2 and Ends in B8 as shown in screenshot.

Comment: @BigSantuary or, if you are in `MS365` and when writing if you have enabled the Beta Channel, then use this one which will return along with the header, `=LET(header,TAKE(A1:B8,1),
name,DROP(A1:B8,1,-1),
value,DROP(A1:B8,1,1),
u,UNIQUE(name),
VSTACK(header,HSTACK(u,SUMIF(name,u,value))))`

Comment: Thanks everyone for suggestions - @EvilBlueMonkey's method worked for me :) I selected the data, inserted a pivot table and set the name field as row & value field as values field, with sum as the option. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @EvilBlueMonkey for the solution in the comments!

I selected the data, inserted a pivot table and set the name field as row & value field as values field, with sum as the option. It displayed my summarized in a new sheet.